# Does Richfaces 4 supports mojo javascript framework

Tags: java, jquery-ui, jsf-2, richfaces, mojo

I am migrating one application from richfaces 3 to richfaces 4,

- While making `ajax call in richfaces 4 entire UI freezes` after making an ajax call.
- This happens because all the **mojo controllers** which are created in DOM, gets vanished after we make an ajax call and hence the page freezes.
- The `controller objects are removed from the DOM` are because the logic which has been **encapsulated inside facelets is not getting rendered** when the `xhtml are converted to HTML`.
- I am using `mojo javascript framework` which works as expected in **richfaces 3** but it doesn't work with **richfaces 4**.

Is there anyone who has solved the similar issue?

Comment: do you have some js code to init that mojo? if so why won't you call it `oncomplete` of your button (if you use a4j:commandButton) or if you use `f:ajax` you can call it on `success`

Comment: I have js code to init mojo and calling it oncomplete of button. I am using <a4j:queue> tag.